# jsf highlight label for invalid input

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

Is there a simple possibility to apply a specific style to input labels that are invalid?

I've seen [omnifaces highlight](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/highlight) component which does the job for the input itself, but the given styleguide for my project, forces this for the label of the input.

Something like this would be great:

```
<h:outputLabel for="inputId" value="label" />
<h:inputText id="inputId" value="..." />

<o:highlight errorLabelStyle="errorLabel" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not possible with `<o:highlight>`. It's however relatively simple to apply the same style class for the labels as well, so it has been [implemented](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/32378886af100c99f3d82ae96c72a28e592c30e2). As per [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) 1.2, you can use it as follows:

```
<h:outputLabel for="inputId" value="label" />
<h:inputText id="inputId" value="..." />

<o:highlight />
```

with the following CSS:

```css
label.error {
    color: red;
}

input.error, select.error, textarea.error {
    background: pink;
}
```

The default stlye class name of `error` is overrideable the usual way:

```
<o:highlight styleClass="invalid" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this was much faster than i ever expected.